# in how many clock pulse a sinus is calculated?

Tags: performance, assembly, x86

The Sinus and Cosinus seem to be very simple in assembly:

```
FSin
FCOS
```

But does it mean they are calculated in one clock cycle?

The calculations behind them seem to be complex.

Comment: Don't most/all FPU ops take more than one cycle?

Comment: Depends on the CPU (Model, year, designer)

Comment: Depends on your histamine levels.

Comment: @CollinD: yup, all FPU ops that really count as FPU math have at least 3 cycle latency in recent Intel designs.  i.e. not counting shuffle, blend, or bitwise AND/OR/XOR on FP data (or anything else that can't generate an FPU exception on a signalling NaN or whatever).  FMA / mul (and in skylake, add/sub) has a **throughput** of 2 vectors or scalars per clock, though, and most CPUs have at worst 1 per clock throughput for basic ops.  So it depends what you mean by "take", although latency is the most sensible interpretation of that phrase (but not the only thing to consider when optimizing).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should we close this as too broad?  Off-site-resource request could also fit, since the direct answer is in [Agner Fog's instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize/).  (Updated on Dec 23 for Broadwell and Skylake CPUs :)  See also the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) wiki.

Explaining why one instruction doesn't mean one cycle is far more complicated, but suffice it to say the micro-coded x87 FPU instructions are slow.  Intel Haswell `fsin`: 47-106c latency.  71-100 uops.

Add/sub / mul/div and sqrt all have fast hardware support.  Skylake can sqrt vectors of 4 single-precision `float` elements with a throughput of one per 3 clocks, vs. per 7 clocks for Haswell.  (Same for scalar: `sqrtps` and `sqrtss` have equal perf on those CPUs.)  Latency is 11 or 12 clocks.

For SSE Sine, find your favourite software implementation and benchmark it.

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the [instruction timings for the 8087](http://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~mckeeman/cs48/mxcom/doc/x87.html), the original Intel floating point unit introduced [in 1980](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Intel_8087) which was a separate chip designed to be paired with an 8088 or 8086 and sold for $90 to $300!

Even though an FABS is a single instruction, it could take anywhere from 10 to 17 clock cycles for it to complete, which is one of the fastest instructions in its repertoire:  Only FCLEX (clear exceptions) is faster at 2 to 8 cycles (no idea why there is such variability—it certainly makes no sense to me).

The slowest single FPU instruction is the FYL2X (Y * log<sub>2</sub> X) at 900 to 1100 cycles.  A standard 8086 was clocked at 5 MHz, so this instruction could take as long as 0.22 milliseconds to execute.  FPU speeds have improved considerably since then!  On the 8086, no instruction executed in [under 2 cycles](http://www.oocities.org/mc_introtocomputers/Instruction_Timing.PDF), and only a few were 2 (like NOP and CBW).

You might note that in that instruction timing table that FSIN and FCOS were not available in the 8087 and 80287.  The compilers provided runtime libraries which used partial transcendental functions of FPU functions to compute them.  When the instructions were first introduced in the 80387, they took between 122 and 771 cycles to execute.  Note that the 387 cycle requirements are "odd" compared to the 8087/80287:  some are quite a bit higher, others are quite a bit lower.

Comment: Maybe FCLEX execution time depended on whether there were any pending exceptions that had to actually be cleared?  Interesting historical perspective; I hadn't even considered answering from this angle.  This really puts Skylake's four single-precision sqrt results per 3 clock cycles in an impressive light!  (or one 80bit x87 FSQRT per 4-7 clocks).